# What is a didatic example of the with-slots macro in CLOS?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, accessor, clos

The Common Lisp HyperSpec [covers](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_slts.htm) the `with-slots` macro. However, the example is hard to grasp.

Is there an easier and more didactic example about it?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/clos.html#getters-and-setters-accessor-reader-writer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To better understand [with-slots](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_slts.htm), one should look into [defclass](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defcla.htm#defclass) first.

> No reader or writer functions are defined by default; their generation must be explicitly requested. However, slots can always be accessed using slot-value.

It means that, unless specific request, `defclass` don't create any accessor for the slots:

```
> (defclass point ()
  (x y))

(let ((new-point (make-instance 'point)))
  (setf (point-x new-point) 1))

Error: The function (COMMON-LISP:SETF COMMON-LISP-USER::POINT-X) is undefined.
```

In this case, one must use the [slot-value](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_slt_va.htm#slot-value) function to access or modify the slot value.

```
(defclass point ()
  (x y))

(let ((new-point (make-instance 'point)))
  (setf (slot-value new-point 'x) 1))
```

Obviously, when there are several slots to update, the code become a little cumbersome:

```
(defmethod translate ((point-instance point) delta-x delta-y)
  (setf (slot-value point-instance 'x)
        (+ (slot-value point-instance 'x) delta-x))
  (setf (slot-value point-instance 'y)
        (+ (slot-value point-instance 'y) delta-y)))
```

For that reason, the [with-slots macro](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_slts.htm) can make the code easier to read:

```
(defmethod translate ((point-instance point) delta-x delta-y)
  (with-slots (x y) point-instance
    (setf x (+ x delta-x))
    (setf y (+ y delta-y))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This (great) [tutorial](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/clos-tutorial/) of 2003 has a good one from the geometry domain.

Create a class to represent points in 3-dimensions:

```lisp
(defclass point ()
    (x y z))
```

Create a variable to instantiate the class and a function to set the values:

```lisp
(defvar my-point
  (make-instance 'point))

(defun set-point-values (point x y z)
  (setf (slot-value point 'x) x
        (slot-value point 'y) y
        (slot-value point 'z) z))
```

In the REPL, do:

```lisp
CL-USER 17 > (set-point-values my-point 3 4 12)
12
```

Now, think about a function to [compute the distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between points. A brute force way would be:

```lisp
(defun brute-force-distance-from-origin (point)
  (let ((x (slot-value point 'x))
        (y (slot-value point 'y))
        (z (slot-value point 'z)))
    (sqrt (+ (* x x)
             (* y y)
             (* z z)))))
```

Using the `with-slots` macro:

```lisp
(defun distance-from-origin (point)
  (with-slots (x y z) point (sqrt (+ (* x x)
                                     (* y y)
                                     (* z z)))))
```

Calling the function in the REPL works as expected:

```lisp
CL-USER> (distance-from-origin my-point)
13.0
```

Comment: I think the setting of values is a distraction from the answer here.  Why not use keyword initialization? `(make-point :x 1 :y 2 :z 3)`

Comment: Hey, you will find a slightly different example but similar explanations on this newer Cookbook: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/clos.html#getters-and-setters-accessor-reader-writer